# How to efficiently merge sort with vectors using C++

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

I have implemented a merge sort in c++ by using vectors as function
arguments instead of indices (start, end). However, I would love to 
know if there is any trade off by doing this, in terms of speed 
and space complexity

The code:

```
void mergeSort(std::vector<int> &array) {
    if(array.size() == 1) return;
    else {
      const unsigned int len = array.size();
      const int lo = floor((double)len/2);
      const int hi = ceil((double)len/2);

      std::vector<int> L(&array[0], &array[lo]);
      std::vector<int> R(&array[lo], &array[len]);

      mergeSort(L);
      mergeSort(R);
      merge(array, L, R);
    }
    return;
}
```

Creating new lists every call to merge sort might not be the way to go,
but this is how the merge sort function works. Also, how fast/slow is the:

```
std::vector<int> L(&array[0], &array[lo]);
```

The merge function then looks like:

```
void merge(
           std::vector<int> &array, 
           std::vector<int> &L, 
           std::vector<int> &R
          ) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator a = array.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator l = L.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator r = R.begin();

    while(l != L.end() && r != R.end()) {
      if (*l <= *r) {
      *a = *l;
      l++;
      }
      else {
        *a = *r;
        r++;
      }
      a++;
   }
   while (l != L.end()) {
     *a = *l;
     a++;
     l++;
   }
   while (r != R.end()) {
     *a = *r;
     a++;
     r++;
   }
   return;
```

}

Comment: The trade-off of using `std::vector` instead of iterators really is just that your algorithm is no longer generic. Since the algorithm itself is using iterators internally, I have trouble finding the advantage. You would really have to test and measure yourself to know if there is any performance advantage.

Comment: Consider posting the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is unlikely to make a noticeable performance difference but doing `lo = len / 2; hi = len - lo;` avoids that floating-point math.

Comment: reserve some length by (l.size() + r.size());   since you made all-in-one method I think using raw data would be faster( l.data() )  and then the duff device and/or omp for-loop optimization. and if you you use this function inside some loop or so then consider do-while is faster

Comment: Is performance the main goal? If so, then for a top down merge sort, do a one time allocation for the working vector, and use mutual recursion to change the direction of the merge depending on the level of recursion. It would be slightly faster to implement a bottom up merge sort. It would be more generic for the input parameters to be pointers to the start and end of either a vector or an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is not need to create new space at each call of merge.
`std::vector<int> L(&array[0], &array[lo]);` will actually create space to accomodate `lo` elements and will perform `lo` copies as well.

You are never gonna use more then `O(n)` additional space for storing values. So, why don't you allocate a buffer large enough accommodate the 
a copy of the whole vector upfront and make each recursive call operate on a specific portion of the data? this way you don't have to create new vectors at each call.

Plus, I will also encourage you to make the `mergesort` works on iterators instead on `vector<int>` only. An interface like the following should be enough.

```
template < typename Iterator, typename Compare>
void mergesort(Iterator s, Iterator e, Compare cmp);
```

[On Github](https://github.com/knotman90/sorting_algorithms/blob/master/source/merge_sort.h) you can find a version of mergesort I have implemented a while ago. It should be enough I guess.

Comment: Having the scratch vector accommodate for types that are not copy-assignable isn't that trivial to get right. Your linked implementation doesn't take that into consideration.

Comment: is not being `move assignable` enough to accommodate this case? Thanks for pointing it out though, I have never thought about this issue before.

Comment: I didn't go through the code very carefully, but I did see that you didn't move the elements. The standard containers are now _very_ loose about their requirements of types to be held, you might want to check them out.

Comment: Great! Thank you @Davide. Better start using those templates. Also, that  `std::distance` looks sweet!

Answer (score 0):

The only additional memory you need for merge sort is array of size `n` for merging any of two sorted `vector`s produced on any step of the algorithm. Obviously, your solution uses more. On first merge it allocates two vectors of `n/2` length , then it will be four vectors of `n/4` and so all, giving `n * log(n)` in total. That's slightly more than `n`.

The cost for allocating `vector` is generally linear from its length (if copying `vector`'s elements can be done in O(1)), but you should remember that allocating memory on the heap is expensive operation if you did not use custom allocator. Allocating memory may issue a system call, which may use complex algorithms to find the continuous piece of memory to satisfy your requirements. It may even need to move already allocated pieces of memory somewhere else. So there's really no point in allocating memory many times if you can stick with just a single allocation.